# Do the temp HP points from a Storm Herald Barbarian's Storm Aura Tundra effect remain when rage ends?

Tags: dnd-5e, class-feature, barbarian, rage, temporary-hit-points

The barbarian archetype [Path of the Storm Herald](https://www.dndbeyond.com/characters/classes/barbarian#PathoftheStormHerald) from *Xanathar's Guide to Everything* has a class feature called Storm Aura (page 10):

> #### Storm Aura
>
> Starting at 3rd level, you emanate an aura while you rage. The aura extends 10 feet from you in every direction, but not through total cover.
>
> Your aura has an effect that activates when you enter your rage, and you can activate the effect again on each of your turns as a bonus action. Choose desert, sea, or tundra. Your aura's effect depends on that chosen environment. You can change your environment choice whenever you gain a level in this class.
>
> If your aura's effects require a saving throw, the DC equals 8 + your proficiency bonus + your Constitution modifier.

The "Tundra" option is described as followed:

> ***Tundra.*** Each creature of your choice in your aura gains 2 temporary hit points, as icy spirits inure it to suffering. The temporary hit points increase when you reach certain levels in this class, increasing to 3 at 5th level, 4 at 10th level, 5 at 15th level, and 6 at 20th level.

Usually, features linked to a barbarian's [Rage](https://www.dndbeyond.com/characters/classes/barbarian#Rage) end when the Rage ends, but from reading these, it appears to me as though these temporary hit points will stick around indefinitely afterwards.

Do these temporary hit points remain after the Rage ends?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

## They last until you complete a long rest

Looking at the general rules for [Temporary Hit Points](https://www.dndbeyond.com/compendium/rules/basic-rules/combat#TemporaryHitPoints) (PHB, pg. 198), it says the following:

> Unless a feature that grants you temporary hit points has a duration, they last until they're depleted or you finish a long rest.

Since the Storm Aura's Tundra option doesn't specify a duration, they will remain until the general rule says they disappear.

This is different to how Rage features usually work, but it could be thought of from a flavour perspective as the Rage was what summoned the "icy spirits", but the temp hit points come from the spirits that are now summoned, rather than from the Rage itself.